# Monadic expressions in conditionals - GHC compiles, cabal refuses

Tags: haskell, cabal

Been scratching my head for a day over this one.

I have a few functions in my code that look like this:

```
function :: IO (Maybe Whatever)
function = do
   monadFun
   yaySomeIO
   status <- maybeItWillFail
   if checkStatus status  -- Did we succeed?
   then monadTime >>= return . Just . processItPurely
   else return Nothing
```

ghci will load and run this interactively with no problems, and ghc will compile it happily.
Running this through cabal, however, gives me this:

```
myProgram.hs:94:16:
Unexpected semi-colons in conditional:
    if checkStatus status; then monadTime >>= return . Just . processItPurely; else return Nothing

Perhaps you meant to use -XDoAndIfThenElse?
```

And whatever this `-XDoAndIfThenElse` option is, I can't seem to find a trace of it anywhere in any documentation. 
Why is cabal (or is this ghc by this point?) yelling at me for using semi-colons that IT put there in the first place? Or is using monadic expressions in if-then-else statements just a bad idea?

Note that cabal doesn't complain about this at all:

```
case checkStatus status of
   True -> monadTime >>= return . Just . processItPurely
   _    -> return Nothing
```

...except this is ugly as hell and I'd never want to put this in my code.
Can anyone tell me what's going on? Please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "correct" way of indenting `if`-expressions in a `do`-block is to indent the `else` and `then` lines further than the `if`, like this.

```
function = do
   monadFun
   yaySomeIO
   status <- maybeItWillFail
   if checkStatus status  -- Did we succeed?
      then monadTime >>= return . Just . processItPurely
      else return Nothing
```

This is because lines with the same amount of indentation in a `do` block are normally treated as separate statements.

However, there is an extension called `DoAndIfThenElse` which will allow you to write it the way you did. This extension was made standard in Haskell 2010, which is why GHC enables it by default.

Cabal tends to require you to be more explicit about these things, so to use it in Cabal, you need to either mention it in your `.cabal` file or add `{-# LANGUAGE DoAndIfThenElse #-}` to the top of your module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just add the indents as necessary!

Comment: With recent versions of Cabal, the pragma is no longer necessary. This question was posted during an interval of a few years in which Haskell 2010 was the default for GHC but not for Cabal.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you can eliminate the if statement by taking advantage of`MaybeT`. Also, `foo >>= return . bar` is the same as `bar <$> foo`. (`<$>` is from `Control.Applicative`, and is the same as `fmap`)

```
function :: MaybeT IO Whatever
function = do
   lift monadFun
   lift yaySomeIO
   status <- lift maybeItWillFail
   guard (checkStatus status)
   processItPurely <$> lift monadTime
```

The only annoyance is the gratuitous sprinkling of `lift`s, but there are ways to get rid of those.

Comment: Once this app is done I need to hit the Haskell books again. Sure I've heard of things like Applicative and Functors, but I've never used them. If more knowledge can make my code sexier then I'm all for it.